# Mongoose.create is adding to database but is still catching an error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to create a RESTful API for products to perform CRUD operations. The Database I am using is MongoDB and I am using mongoose with express to access the data. When I try to create a product it adds the product to database and I want to send the information of created data to the user but it sends the data from catch block and error displayed is null.

My Schema

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: {type:String, required:true},
    price: {type:Number, required:true}
})

let product = mongoose.model("User",userSchema);
```

Endpoint for creating a product

```
app.post("/addprod" ,(req,res) => {
    let prodname = req.body.name
    let price = req.body.price
    product.create({
        "_id" : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        "name" : prodname,
        "price":price
    })
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
        res.json({
            _id:res._id,
            name:res.name,
            price:res.price,
            request:{
                method:"GET",
                url: "localhost:3000/prod?name=" + res.name 
            }
        })
    }
    )
    .catch(err => res.json({
        message1:err
    }))
})
```

The console output

```
{ _id: 5d188eb5ea237a204caba7c7,
  name: 'shaurya10',
  price: 3000,
  __v: 0 }
```

I expect the output to be

```
{
    "_id":"5d188eb5ea237a204caba7c7",
    "name":"shaurya10",
    "price":"3000",
    "request":{
        "method":"GET",
        "url": "localhost:3000/prod?name=shaurya10" 
}
```

The output I am getting is

```
{
    "message1": {}
}
```

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: what is your console output of res?

Comment: @MdAlamin I have edited the post to add console output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `res` as response variable in both outer function and inner function

You can simply do this.

```
app.post("/addprod" ,(req,res) => { 
   let prodname = req.body.name 
   let price = req.body.price
   product.create({ 
      "_id" : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(), 
      "name" : prodname, 
      "price":price 
   }).then(item => {
         res.send(item);
   }).catch(err => {
         res.send(err);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably the product name and price is empty. You define them as required fields:

```
    name: {type:String, required:true},
    price: {type:Number, required:true}
```

Change your code:

```
    let prodname = req.body.name || 'sample product'
    let price = req.body.price || '20'
```

Then check the result.

Comment: I am sending the product name and price and when i check all the products in my local mongodb the product has been added according to that name and price

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use json for sending repsonse... you can do like this (**shortest and well-formatted**)

```
app.post("/addprod", (req,res) => { 
   product.create({ 
      "_id" : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(), 
      "name": req.body.name, 
      "price": req.body.price
   }).then(product => {
         res.json(product);
   }).catch(err => {
         res.json(err);
   });
});
```